# What cameras can I connect to the CSI connector?

Tags: peripherals, camera

The model B comes with a [MIPI Camera Serial Interface](http://www.mipi.org/specifications/camera-interface) connector, but it's hard to find a store that'll sell you a chip or camera to interface with it.

The only thing I've found so far is the the product brief for a [HDMI-CSI converter by Toshiba](http://www.toshiba.com/taec/components/ProdBrief/10L02_TC358743_ProdBrief.pdf), but no way to buy it.

So where should I go to find a camera that can interface with the RP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the moment, it seems you can't, but the foundation are apparently planning to sell cameras you can plug in in the future (or at least they were last year):

> Usually the camera requires two interfaces, the CSI 2 or CCP 2 port for the image data coming from the camera, and I2C to actually tell the camera what to do.
>
> Next year the foundation will be selling a camera that you should be able to plug straight in - for the moment the CSI port is fairly unusable without an already supported camera - they need drivers on the GPU which cannot be written 'at home'.
>
> There also the question of getting the camera data in to Arm Linux land from the GPU.
>
> All this stuff will be sorted out when the proposed camera comes next year.
>
> In the meantime you could use a USB camera.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1678

Comment: This thread has a lot of good info on the progress of that camera. http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=6120

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer is out of date.

The official camera is available from most channels that sell the Raspberry Pi.

I don't believe that there are any other cameras working with that interface though (yet!)

However some people have used additional lenses or removed the IR filter for their special purposes/needs.

Comment: Farnell sells also NOIR version of the camera, which has the IR filter removed.

Answer (score 4):

In principle, any CSI camera will work. In practice, this isn't true. For the camera to work, drivers have to be written and that requires you to have access to code Broadcom haven't released.

The Foundation will release an officially supported camera module soon. I can't wait!

Answer (score 3):

The world of Pi and csi-2 has become a much better place since that question was asked, but if anyone comes wandering here the way I did,here's a little something:

[CSI2 Raspberry Camera Modules](http://wonderfulengineering.com/10-best-raspberry-pi-camera-modules/)