# What are S2 and S5 connectors for?

Tags: hardware, connectors

On the RasPI there are two ZIF-Connectors S2 and S5. What are they for?

I looked at the [schematics](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Raspberry-Pi-Schematics-R1.0.pdf) page 4 - F4 to F8 and assume that S5 could be the camera connector mentioned [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113/what-cameras-can-i-connect-to-the-csi-connector). S2 could be some kind of display interface, but I'm not quite sure.

Can anyone provide information about this ports and what hardware could be attached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The S2 and S5 are [DSI](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#DSI) (display) and [MIPI CSI](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#MIPI_CSI-2)-2 (camera) interfaces respectively.

I don't know of any projects that currently make use of these connectors, but that doesn't mean they don't exist. The Foundation has plans to release a camera later this year, and the new opensource GPU dirvers may allow others to get displays working with the DSI interface.

Answer (score 1):

There are now (as of November 2013) two camera modules available to connect to the S5 header: a regular one and one without an infrared filter on top of the CCD.

See http://www.raspberrypi.org/camera and http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/5128

They're available for purchase through most of the same distributors that sell the Raspberry Pi.